Laptop has a black screen after making changes to the BIOS?
I have a Samsung NP270E5J, I wanted to make some changes in the BIOS and since then it doesn't start anymore.
The LED is on but the screen remains black.
What can I do?

What changes have you made and can't you undo what you did?
